# Confusion with set notation

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

If you wanted to state a set of every single number ever, would
$$ C $$
just suffice, or is it correct to say:
$$ \{ x \in C | -\infty \lt x \lt \infty \} $$
where 'C' is the complex set.

Comment: If you want to specify all the complex numbers you can say $\mathbb C$. Your set notation's incorrect because there's no $<$ relation in the complex numbers.

Comment: If you're talking about numbers in the naive sense then the set of the real numbers would contain "every single number ever". People often use the notation $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the set of all real numbers. There is no natural order on the set of complex numbers, so, the set $\{ x\in \mathbb{C} :  -\infty < x < \infty \}$ does not even make sense unless you decide to put an order on the set of complex numbers.

Comment: What is a number, though?

Comment: @ashK Yes, I didn't know you couldn't compare complex numbers. So {x∈R:−∞<x<∞} would be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex set $\mathbb C$ doesn't have an order relation between its numbers.

You can't compare $3+4i$ and $1-i$, the same way you can't compare vectors.

By abuse of notation, $\mathbb C \cong \mathbb R ^2$

So, if you wanted to write a set of every single number in existence, it depends on what you consider as a ''number''.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you couldn't compare complex numbers. Thanks for the help!